# Facebook workplace rejecting valid SAML response token

Tags: c#, .net, facebook, single-sign-on, saml

I'm trying to validate facebook workplace users with my own identity provider. I've successfully generated the response token and also checked its validity from onelogin saml-response validator. But, the facebook isn't accepting the token. I successfully authenticated the users on facebook workplace using ADFS. Comparing the two tokens (ADFS generated and my custom IDP generated), there is only one difference that the ADFS signature tag uses "ds" prefix like.  while mine doesn't (just ). So, my question is that is it necessary to use this prefix while authenticating users for facebook.
Also, I can't find any solution to add the "ds" prefix to my token. Manually adding it invalidates the signature.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

I'm using c# and .NET.

Answer (score 0):

The .NET framework's SignedXml class doesn't add the ds prefix and doesn't support specifying a prefix.
However, this shouldn't matter as XML signature implementations should not rely on prefixes. Elements are identified by their name and namespace not the prefix.

We have successfully SSO'd to Facebook without using ds prefixes so SSO must be failing for some other reason.